# SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() is null in JWT authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, jwt

im trying to do simple JWT authorization application like here: https://github.com/eazybytes/spring-security/tree/main/section9/springsecsection9

but my authentication in JWTTokengeneratorFilter is null and I don't have a idea why.

I can do it the old way with attemptAuthentication methods etc. and it works great, but I wanted to do it like in this tutorial and I can't se what am I doing wrong here.

Can some one tell me what am I missing here?

**AuthSecurityConfig.class**

```
@Configuration
public class AuthSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .cors().configurationSource(request -> {
                    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
                    config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:3000"));
                    config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
                    config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                    config.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization"));
                    config.setMaxAge(3600L);
                    return config;
                }).and().csrf().disable()
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTTokenValidatorFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(new JWTTokenGeneratorFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
                        .antMatchers( "/login").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/register").authenticated()
                        .antMatchers("/user").permitAll()
                ).httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

**JWTTokenGeneratorFilter.class**

```
public class JWTTokenGeneratorFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();  // here authentication is null
        if (null != authentication) {
            SecretKey key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(SecurityConstants.JWT_KEY.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            String jwt = Jwts.builder().setIssuer("Pollongz").setSubject("JWT Token")
                    .claim("username", authentication.getName())
                    .claim("authorities", populateAuthorities(authentication.getAuthorities()))
                    .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                    .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + 300000000))
                    .signWith(key).compact();
            response.setHeader(SecurityConstants.JWT_HEADER, jwt);
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return !request.getServletPath().equals("/login");
    }

    private String populateAuthorities(Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> collection) {
        Set<String> authoritiesSet = new HashSet<>();
        for (GrantedAuthority authority : collection) {
            authoritiesSet.add(authority.getAuthority());
        }
        return String.join(",", authoritiesSet);
    }
}
```

**JWTTokenValidatorFilter.class**

```
public class JWTTokenValidatorFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        String jwtToken = request.getHeader(SecurityConstants.JWT_HEADER);
        if (null != jwtToken) {
            try {
                SecretKey key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(
                        SecurityConstants.JWT_KEY.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

                Claims claims = Jwts.parserBuilder()
                        .setSigningKey(key)
                        .build()
                        .parseClaimsJws(jwtToken)
                        .getBody();
                String username = String.valueOf(claims.get("username"));
                String authorities = (String) claims.get("authorities");

                Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username,null,
                        AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(authorities));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid Token received!");
            }

        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }


    @Override protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getServletPath().equals("/login"); }
}
```

**AuthUserDetails.class**

```
@Service
public class AuthUserDetails implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public AuthUserDetails(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(username);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User details not found for the user : " + username);
        }
        return new UserDetailsSecurity(user);
    }
}
```

**UserDetailsSecurity.class**

```
public class UserDetailsSecurity implements UserDetails {

    private final User user;

    public UserDetailsSecurity(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

        return Stream.of(user.getRoles().split(","))
                .map(role -> "ROLE_" + role.toUpperCase())
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .stream()
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getEmail();
    }

    //.. other override methods
}
```

**AuthApplication.class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScans({ @ComponentScan("com.vue.auth.controller"), @ComponentScan("com.vue.auth.config")})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.vue.auth.repository")
@EntityScan("com.vue.auth.model")
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class AuthApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```